# Enterprise architect: Order of entry/exit functions in states

Tags: state-machine, enterprise-architect

In my state machine, I have a state with several entry and exit functions. Enterprise Architect sorts them alphabetically, which can lead to something like this:

```
entry / a 
exit / b
entry / c
```

The entry and exit functions are what EA calls "element operations".

**Question:** How can I change the order of these operations? Ideally, I'd like to be able to order them in any way; if that is not possible, I'd like to have all the entry functions before the exit functions.

**What I tried:** In the "operations"-dialog, one can sort by columns; however, this does not change the order in the state diagram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the operations dialog you have select an operation and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>UP</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>DOWN</kbd> to change the order of the operation.

Alternatively right click and choose option `Move up` or `Move down`

Comment: Great, thanks! Though I do have to say, this is really unintuitive - if I sort by column, the order does not change in the state diagram, only in the operations dialog.

Comment: @mort i think EA should get the prize for most unintuitive UI, it is horrible!

Answer (score 3):

I'm using EA 14, and there is a checkbox on "Start > View > Preferences > Objects" (Ctrl+F9 > Objects) named "Sort Features Alphabetically". I have just unchecked it and the operations now appear in the chronological order (entry, do, exit). I haven't checked the impact on other diagrams, though.