# How to change operation order in enterprise architect？

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I am currently using Enterprise Architect 14, when creating operations into a state, three typical operations can be added: entry, do, exit.
But in the state machine diagram, the order of the operations is aleph based, I want to know how to change the order or just fix the order as: entry, do, exit.
[Current Order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHd5k.png) 
Current Order may be: exit, do , entry or other alphabetically

I believe it can be changed ([a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291179/enterprise-architect-order-of-entry-exit-functions-in-states)) but still cannot find where to change it, a picture may be quite helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enterprise architect: Order of entry/exit functions in states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291179/enterprise-architect-order-of-entry-exit-functions-in-states)

Comment: @GeertBellekens I tried that in V14 but it does not work (damn GUI). Might be that my wine/Mac messes up? No Green Arrows. Can someone please send the storm troopers to Sparx' site?

Comment: @ThomasKilian There are no green arrows to be pressed. just Ctrl + Arrow Up/Down

Comment: @GeertBellekens I know there are none (why? Just rhetorical) . Ctrl-U/D does not work here.

Comment: Thanks guys, for other elements other than states in EA, Ctrl + Arrow Up/Down can work.
However, for states, the operation diagram is organized differently, and Ctrl + Arrow Up/Down cannot work.

Comment: @GeertBellekens  This issue still not solved, if any update, please leave a message below